# Filter dataframe based on values in multiple columns - column names can change

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| Test | LSL | USL | Day0 | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 100 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 200 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 20 | 5 | 5 | 20 |
| 4 | 10 | 100 | 20 | 20 | 20 | 20 |

I want to keep all rows where at least one value in columns Day0-Day3 is less than LSL or greater than USL. In my example the dataframe I need is:

| Test | LSL | USL | Day0 | Day1 | Day2 | Day3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 100 | 10 | 10 | 10 | 200 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 20 | 5 | 5 | 20 |

The number of columns and the names of columns for Day0-Day3 can change. For example, I could have:

| Test | LSL | USL | Week0 | Week1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 100 | 10 | 200 |
| 2 | 0 | 100 | 10 | 10 |
| 3 | 10 | 100 | 20 | 5 |
| 4 | 10 | 100 | 20 | 20 |

I have not been able to figure out how to do this, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find max, min values across columns and compare it with "LSL" and "USL" values to create a mask to filter `df` with:

```
max_vals = df.drop(columns=['Test','LSL','USL']).max(axis=1)
min_vals = df.drop(columns=['Test','LSL','USL']).min(axis=1)
mask = (df['LSL'] > min_vals) | (df['USL'] < max_vals)
out = df[mask]
```

Output:

```
Test  LSL  USL  Day0  Day1  Day2  Day3
0     1    0  100    10    10    10   200
2     3   10  100    20     5     5    20
```

For the second example:

```
   Test  LSL  USL  Week0  Week1
0     1    0  100     10    200
2     3   10  100     20      5
```

Comment: Thanks!!  This really helped me out.  All three answers will work for me.   I used this one because I needed to add another condition to the filtering.

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple conditions and boolean indexing.

```
use_cols = df[[c for c in df.columns if c[-1].isdigit()]]
df.loc[(use_cols.lt(df['LSL'].values) | (use_cols.gt(df['USL'].values))).any(1)]

   Test  LSL  USL  Day0  Day1  Day2  Day3
0     1    0  100    10    10    10   200
2     3   10  100    20     5     5    20
```

---

We are basically evaluating two conditions:

1. is a value in `use_cols` columns less than LSL? ([`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html))
2. is a value in `use_cols` columns greater than LSL? ([`gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html))

To use multiple conditions, using or `|` per se, you use brackets `()` surrounding each condition, and by chaining `any(axis=1)` checks whether at least 1 `True` is returned.

To allow for different column names, one idea would to select the columns that end with a digit (i.e. Week0, Day0, Month1, Year2 etc). However keep in mind that if any other column ends with a digit it will be included here. Or, equivalently, if the columns are always at a specific position you can use `iloc`. This requires some domain knowledge that you have.

Comment: This misses the requirement that the columns could have different names, e.g. Week0, Week1, ...

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated accordingly.